# Handling both mouse move and mouse click on a tray icon

Tags: winapi, vb6, system-tray, trayicon

My VB6 application is usually hidden and has a tray icon. It currently handles a user-defined callback as per this code:

```
Public Const WM_USER = &H400
Public Const TRAY_CALLBACK = (WM_USER + 1001&)
With GTStruct
    .uID = mId
    .hwnd = frm.hwnd
    .hIcon = frm.Icon.Handle
    .UFlags = NIF_ICON Or NIF_MESSAGE
    .uCallbackMessage = TRAY_CALLBACK        
    .cbSize = Len(GTStruct)
End With
Shell_NotifyIcon NIM_ADD, GTStruct
```

A WindowProc handles TRAY_CALLBACK and the click message:

```
Const WM_NCDESTROY = &H82
Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

' If we're being destroyed, remove the tray icon
' and restore the original WindowProc.
If Msg = WM_NCDESTROY Or Msg = WM_CLOSE Then
    RemoveFromTray
ElseIf Msg = TRAY_CALLBACK Then
    ' The user clicked on the tray icon.
    ' Look for click events.
    If lParam = WM_RBUTTONUP Then
        ' On right click, show the menu.
        SetForegroundWindow TheForm.hwnd
        TheForm.PopupMenu TheMenu
        If Not (TheForm Is Nothing) Then
            PostMessage TheForm.hwnd, WM_NULL, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
```

As it is, the application works and right-clickign the icon brings up the menu. I want to handle the mouse_move message in addition to this existing callback message so I changed the callback to this:

```
.uCallbackMessage = TRAY_CALLBACK Or WM_MOUSEMOVE
```

However, this ignores the mousemove message. If I use :

```
.uCallbackMessage = WM_MOUSEMOVE
```

The mouse_move message works and Form_MouseMove is called properly but then the menu stops working.

**The question**

How can I specify multiple callbacks in order to handle both the mouse move and the mouse click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one callback message per icon; in your case, this is `TRAY_CALLBACK`. When you receive this message the `lParam` value indicates which mouse message triggered your callback.

In your example code you're already comparing `lParam` against `WM_RBUTTONUP`. You just need to add an additional check against `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.